# Find out if QCursor::setPos has an effect

Tags: c++, qt, accessibility

`QCursor::setPos()` does not work on some platforms under some conditions. E.g. on MacOS, there are accessibility settings, allowing an application to allow or forbid controlling the cursor. Is there a way to find out whether `QCursor::setPos()` currently has an effect?

The most trivial solution, changing the cursor slightly using `QCursor::setPos` and check whether it changed (using `QCursor::pos`) did not work, at least not on MacOS.

**Note:** A generic solution for at least Linux, Windows, Mac, is required.

Comment: Are you interested in a general solution, or something specific to MacOS?

Comment: MacOS is just an example where I could not find out whether `QCursor::setPos` has an effect. However, the solution must work on all systems, or at very least, Linux, Windows, MacOS.

Answer (score 4):

A cross-platform solution is not known to me, which does not mean there is none. But for macOS you can use platform-specific code.

**macOS solution**

There is the AXIsProcessTrusted function in the ApplicationServices framework of macOS, it

> Returns whether the current process is a trusted accessibility client.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1460720-axisprocesstrusted?language=objc

In addition to calling the above function, you need to:

- use the `Q_OS_MAC` preprocessor conditional to include macOS specific code
- link against the ApplicationServices framework
- use the include `#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>`

**Example**

A complete self-contained example could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#endif

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        this->setWindowTitle("Qt Cursor Test");
        this->resize(320, 240);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication appl(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainw_window;
    mainw_window.show();

    QCursor cursor;

#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    if(AXIsProcessTrusted()) {
        std::cout << "trusted accessibility client" << std::endl;
        cursor.setPos(10,10);
    } else {
        std::cout << "not a trusted trusted accessibility client, so give the user a hint or do whatever is appropriate" << std::endl;
    }
#else
    cursor.setPos(10,10);
#endif

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

**Building**

You need to link against the `ApplicationServices` framework. In case you are using CMake for building it could look like this:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
 project(CursorTest)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
 set(Qt5_DIR "/usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.14.1/lib/cmake/Qt5/")

 find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

 add_executable(CursorTest main.cpp)

 target_link_libraries(CursorTest PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets  "-framework ApplicationServices")
```

**System Dialog**

Perhaps you want to show the system dialog for MacOS users, that explains that the application wants to have accessibility  trust in and offers to open the system defaults, which would look like this:

[image: macOS system dialog]

Then you would use `Boolean AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(CFDictionaryRef options)`, which

> Returns whether the current process is a trusted accessibility client.
>
> options
>
> A dictionary of options, or NULL to specify no options. The following options are available:
>   KEY: kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt VALUE: ACFBooleanRef indicating whether the user will be informed if the current process is untrusted. This could be used, for example, on application startup to always warn a user if accessibility is not enabled for the current process. Prompting occurs asynchronously and does not affect the return value.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1459186-axisprocesstrustedwithoptions?language=objc

Just slightly modify the above example:

```
...
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    CFStringRef keys[] = { kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt };
    CFTypeRef values[] = { kCFBooleanTrue };
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL,
                                                 (const void **)&keys,
                                                 (const void **)&values,
                                                 sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]),
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                 &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    if(AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)) {
        std::cout << "trusted accessibility client" << std::endl;
        cursor.setPos(10,10);
    } else {
        std::cout << "not a trusted trusted accessibility client, so give the user a hint or do whatever is appropriate" << std::endl;
    }
    CFRelease(options);
#else
...
```

Comment: Thanks, having it for one system is better than nothing, but hopefully there will be a solution that works for all operating systems.